# download Image in android

Tags: java, android

i am working on my android application and trying to download an Image from web server (Local Host IIS7).but unfortunately my app doesn't work.actually when i run my app it doesn't show any picture inside the ImageView . 
I compiled my app but i didn't find any error in logCat! it seemed every thing was ok.there was only one exotic message :

> Choreographer skipped 32 frames
>   but according to my Research , i think it cant impact my application. 
>   one more thing i think , onPostExcute is not Run.but i cant find the reason. 
>   Here is my code :

```
public class Ads extends Activity {

    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException{
        InputStream in=null; 
        int response=-1;
        URL url=new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn =url.openConnection();
        if(!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an Http connection ");
        try{
            HttpURLConnection httpConn=(HttpURLConnection)conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response=httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if(response== HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                in=httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Log.d("NetWorking",ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
        }
        return in; 
    }
    private Bitmap DownloadImag(String URL){
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        InputStream in=null;
        try{
            in=OpenHttpConnection(URL);
            bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();

        }catch(IOException e1){
            Log.d("NetworkActivity",e1.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
    public class DownloadImages extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String...urls){
            return DownloadImag(urls[0]);
        }
        protected void onPostExcute(Bitmap result){
            try{
            Log.d("Setting ImgView","Ok");
            ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            img.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
            catch(Exception ex){
                Log.d("Setting ImgView","Error");
            }
        }
    }
    /** Called when the activity first created */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ads);
        Log.d("Start-Working", "ok");
        new DownloadImages().execute("http://10.0.2.2:80/Urgence/document/img/my.jpg");
    }   
}
```

what should i do ?!

Comment: see your onPostExecute() method. The name of method is not correct. Its not giving u any error???

Comment: Look into intentService and Broadcast receivers ... Google it as there is a lot of info about downloading files in the background.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one library for faster image loading,
it cache image with quality you ask for.

[Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

it's easy to implement as snippet given in page.

You also can get bitmap like....

```
// Load image, decode it to Bitmap and return Bitmap synchronously
Bitmap bmp = imageLoader.loadImageSync(imageUri);
```